# Go to previous route programmatically

Tags: navigation, kendo-ui, single-page-application

If I have 2 routes and in the markup of the first one I have a link like:

```
<a href="#/secondPage"/>
```

and I click on that link (or using the `router.nagigate("/secondPage")` method) I will go to the second page.

If in that `secondPage` I have a button that should close the `secondPage` and return to the previous one. Like the back button of the browser.

How could I do that?

```
$("#my-button").click(function(){
   //How to navigate to previous page?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use router.navigate with "#:back"

```
router.navigate("#:back");
```

See sample (Orders and Products tab have back buttons) http://jsbin.com/uvuviWA/3